# How can I delete any voice channel on Discord after 3 minutes if the channel is not full?

Tags: python, timer, discord, bots, channel

I'm programming a discord bot using Python, I just want to know how to delete any voice channel after 3 minutes from its creation, under a specific category if a voice channel is not full (user_limit =10).

I appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Get the members in a voice channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.members)
[Get the user limit of a voice channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.user_limit)
[Delete the channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceChannel.delete)

Please try to research a little before asking a question.
Split up your code into the operations you want to do and search for them, in this case

- **Wait** 3 minutes
- Get **members in a channel**
- Check if the amount of members in that channel equal to the **channel user limit**
- If not, **delete the channel**

If you still can't find a solution then ask for help, but you probably could've figured this out by yourself.